# JavaScipt window.location

Tags: javascript, html, window.location

How to make the tic tac toe game refresh the page and open exactly on the game page when it's over? Right now it opens the game page but doesn't refresh it

```
<span class="menu">Contacts</span>
<span class="menu">Gallery</span>
<span class="menu">Calculator</span>
<span class="menu" id="game">Game</span>
<span class="menu">About</span>
<span class="menu">Slider</span>
```

`window.location="index.html";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `location.reload` method.

```js
window.location.reload();
```